# Windows Batch file - can't get variable to store fill file name with spaces

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to setup a batch file that will run a series of files on multiple processors, I've got the code worked out, but the one remaining problem I have is in this section of the code. Basically, the %%f does store the full file name including characters after a space. However, when it gets to the %1 it drops off all the characters after a space in the file name.

Does anyone know how to change this so it retains the full file name? Thanks!

```
for /R %%f in (*.nas) do call :runnastran %%f

:runnastran
    start "mywindow" "c:\test\nastran.exe" "c:\test\nastran.ini" "%1"

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes on %%f.  One could argue that then you don't need them on %1.  If you do use them on %1 you should do "%~1", which will move existing quotes if they exist and add quotes.  That way you are safe if quotes are not used when calling and youy don't end up with 2 sets of quotes if they are used in the call.

```
for /R %%f in (*.nas) do call :runnastran "%%f"

:runnastran start "mywindow" "c:\test\nastran.exe" "c:\test\nastran.ini" "%~1"

pause
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You are a life saver. I made the changes and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of remember, when you work with paths in DOS, you can either do it this way

```
"c:\Dir1\Dir1.1\File.ext"
```

or this way

```
c:\"Dir One"\"Dir One.One"\"File X.ext"
```